# Margin 0 auto won't fully center a div

Tags: html, css

I have code to center a `div` on an HTML page.
My problem is that `margin: 0 auto` only centers the `div` horizontal, but I want it fully centered, so also vertically.

```css
body{
  background-position: center;
  background: #0a056f;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #0a056f 0%, #054fb5 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #0a056f 0%,#054fb5 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #0a056f 0%,#054fb5 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#0a056f', endColorstr='#054fb5', GradientType=1);
}

.login_register_recover_box{
  background-color: #fff;
  background-position: center;
  -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 50px 5px #091079;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 5px #091079;
  box-shadow:         0px 0px 50px 5px #091079;
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/custom/reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/custom/custom1.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="login_register_recover_box">&nbsp;fdfdss</div>
</body>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Small tip about your css. According to http://shouldiprefix.com/#box-shadow you don't need to use prefixes webkit and moz for box-shadow as it's already supported by all browsers. 
By the way, when you ask questions you should provide only important html and css and in this case all background gradients are unnecessary. :)

Comment: Check out this solution: **https://jsfiddle.net/mk36h6xq/**, it should also fix your gradient issue. Unfortunately I can't post it as an answer anymore, because your question is marked as *duplicate*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use flexbox

```css
body{
    background-position: center;
    background: #0a056f;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
    min-height:100vh;
}

.login_register_recover_box{
    background-color: #fff;
    background-position: center;
    width: 75%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

    <div class="login_register_recover_box">&nbsp;
        fdfdss
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead, you can use **[flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)** to achieve the same.

To center a div inside a parent, you can apply `display:flex` on the parent element along with `align-items:center` and `justify-content:center;`.

With `align-items:center`, the children are ***vertically*** centered inside parent.

With `justify-content:center`, the children are ***horizontally*** centered inside parent.

You can learn more at: **[A complete guide to CSS-FlexBox Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)**

```css
.parent{
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  background:red;
}
.centered{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='centered'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @downvoter, please do comment.

Comment: When using flexbox, align-items:center positions all child elements in the vertical center. If you want only a specific child to be in the center you can use align-self:center. It's just a small tip :)